# web.config redirection with query string to another domain

Tags: asp.net, web-config, redirect

I have the current location on my website:

```
http://my-domain.com/ccy/app.html?from=GBP&to=EUR...
```

and I would like to use web.config to redirect all calls to `/ccy` folder to another domain containing the same query string, so it goes to.

```
http://my-other-domain.com/another-folder/app.html?from=GBP&to=EUR
```

How it is possible to achieve that using IIS7?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Url Rewrite module](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) in IIS 7. The following rule should work for you case:

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="DynamicRewrite" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="ccy/(.*)" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html" matchType="IsFile" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="http://my-other-domain.com/another-folder/{R:1}.html" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>  
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: thanks Darin, but this seems to be redirecting to `/error?aspxerrorpath=/ccy/app.html` instead?

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use mod rewrite to rewrite any requests for ccy to another-folder.

Here's a link covering mod rewrite for IIS7.

http://www.micronovae.com/ModRewrite/ModRewrite.html